# Error : No Valid proxy found in config when trying to connect via proxychains

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kali-linux

I am new to linux and trying to set up a proxy based but getting this error. Not sure what i m doing wrong. I will appreciate any help I can get.

```
$ proxychains firefox www.whatsmyip.org
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /us/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
error: no valid proxy found in config
```

```
$ nano /etc/proxychains4.conf
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#   

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns 

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#       http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#       socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#       http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#       
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
# socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  127.0.0.1 9050
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output from your proxychains:

```
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
```

and look at the name of your config file:

```
$ nano /etc/proxychains4.conf
```

You'll see that these are two different files...

Suggest you rename your proxychains4.conf to proxychains.conf.