# Error : No Valid proxy found in config

Tags: x-server, proxychains

I Write an PHP Code for my Project & Getting issue of Error : No Valid proxy found in config

I have attached the Screenshot, Someone Have any idea to fix this issue & Add that file in config,
[image]

Thanks

This one is my Output as /etc/proxychains.conf

[image: Output 1]
[image: Output 2]
[image: Output 3]
[image: Output 4]

Comment: It is possible this is an issue of misdirected configuration files. Can you post your config file as well as the full output of the command you screenshoted. `/etc/proxychains.conf` Additionally, you can refer to this post for what I believe the issue may be: [Error : No Valid proxy found in config when trying to connect via proxychains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/670652)

Comment: Hello I Have added the Screenshot of my Error, Or If You can help me Come over any Social media, Its Really Urgent for me to fix that one issue

Comment: Ok, so you have it configured. Check out this previous question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670652/error-no-valid-proxy-found-in-config-when-trying-to-connect-via-proxychains and run the command there. In the output, what does it show is being used as the configuration file? Is it /etc/proxychains.conf?